# How to check the string is empty after replace all <br/> and &nbsp; in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to replace all `<br />` tags and `&nbsp;` character from the data of ckeditor and validate if it's empty will alert an error. But somehow if i press enter multiple time in ckeditor, it will generate  multiple line with content like this:

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
&nbsp;
```

I wrote this code and try to console out the result but it print out something like a blank string with break lines, not `<empty string>`. Is there any wrong in my code?

```js
var str = "<br />\n"+
"<br />\n"+
"<br />\n"+
"<br />\n"+
"<br />\n"+
"&nbsp;";

str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/gm,'');
str = str.replace(/^\s*$/gm,'');
str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gm, "");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: How did you run that at all? You can't put line breaks in a JavaScript string literal. You could do it using a template literal.

Comment: Sorry for my accidentally, i have updated my code

Answer (score 1):

Finnally, i found the resolution. I also have to remove `\n` in string, the code will run properly.

```
str = str.replace(/\n/gm,'');
```

Comment: That was another solution I was going to post, but my answer worked more simply.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about why replace ````\n```` is the problem

Comment: Yes, I know it works because it worked for me.

Comment: But `\s*` matches `\n`.

Comment: Oh really? I think they are different escapse characters, doesn't it?

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace. Whitespace includes space, tab, and newline. `\n` is newline.

Answer (score 0):

You're not replacing the newlines after each `<br/>`.

You can solve this by moving the replacement of empty lines to *after* you remove `<br/>`

```js
var str = `<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
&nbsp;`;

str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/gm,'');
str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gm, "");
str = str.replace(/^\s*$/gm,'');

console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

Comment: i founded problem and way to resolve as i post above...Thanks :D